# Xamarin Java.Lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id

Tags: c#, json, xamarin.forms

Hola amigos estoy recibiendo un **Json** en mi app en **Xamarin** pero al tratar de recibir en especifico 2 parametros **int** me aparece este error ...

> Java.Lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x18 (unknown) for fragment FragmentContainer{a5f3e73 #1 id=0x18}

Jamás me había pasado , al estar debuggeando mi método me doy cuenta que cuando trato de convertir los parametros que recibo, la respuesta me da **null**. Quisiera saber si alguien sabe que estoy haciendo mal D:

```js
try {
  var response = await client.PostAsync("mipaginabienpadre:3",
    content);

  switch (response.StatusCode) {
    case (System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK):
      res_Label_api.Text = "good";

      var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

      member = new Member();
      memberdatabase = new MemberDatabase();
      member.Name = userName;
      member.Pass = pass;
      member.Firma = firma;
      member.Token_Type = tok_ty;
      member.Access_Token = acc_tok;

      var xjson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject < RootObject > (responseString); //hasat aquí todo parece funcionar , o al menos puedo ver que me devuelve un json

      int xid;
      Int32.TryParse(xjson.DatosEnvio.IdUsuario, out xid);
      member.ID = xid;


      member.AdminType = xjson.DatosEnvio.AdminType.ToString();

      memberdatabase.AddMember(member);


      Application.Current.MainPage = new NavigationPage(new PageNav());


  }
} catch (Exception ex) {

  await DisplayAlert("", "" + ex.ToString(), "ok");
}
```

este es el modelo que estoy usando ...

```js
public class Tabla {
  public List < Table > Table {
    get;
    set;
  }
}

public class RootObject {
  public DatosEnvio DatosEnvio {
    get;
    set;
  }
  public DatosEnvioJson DatosEnvioJson {
    get;
    set;
  }
  public Tablas Tablas {
    get;
    set;
  }
  public string bandera {
    get;
    set;
  }
  public string mensaje {
    get;
    set;
  }
}

public class DatosEnvio {
  public string Usuario {
    get;
    set;
  }
  public string IdUsuario {
    get;
    set;
  }
  public string Nombre {
    get;
    set;
  }
  public int AdminType {
    get;
    set;
  }

}

public class Dato {
  public int IdUsuario {
    get;
    set;
  }
  public string Usuario {
    get;
    set;
  }
  public string Nombre {
    get;
    set;
  }
}
```

y mi respuesta

```js
{
    "DatosEnvio": {},
    "DatosEnvioJson": {
        "Table": {
            "campos": [
                "IdUsuario",
                "Usuario",
                "Nombre",
                "AdminType"
            ],
            "datos": [
                {
                    "IdUsuario": 1,
                    "Usuario": "root",
                    "Nombre": "Administrador",
                    "AdminType": 3
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "tablas": null,
    "bandera": "0",
    "mensaje": "1"
}
```

Comment: Imagino que estás usando NewtonsoftJson. La estructura de objetos debe coincidir con la estructura del json, para que el parseo sea limpio. ¿Has mirado que todos los atributos de tu variable "xjson" sean correctos? Es decir, ¿todos están a null? ¿o algunos se han deserializado bien?

Comment: no dehecho en xjson todo parece ser recibido(deserializado) con normalidad el problema es que no puedo agregarlos a mi sqli ni puedo parcerarlos 
> Int32.TryParse(xjson.DatosEnvio.IdUsuario, out xid); en esta linea IdUsuario es = null

Comment: xjson.DatosEnvio.IdUsuario hace referencia, si sigues el camino de tu modelo, un string que pertenece al objeto DatosEnvio, y en tu Json DatosEnvio es {} (vacío)

Answer (score 2):

El error que te esta dando no esta relacionado con Json, es un error de Android.

Googleando un poco veo que hay gente que ha tenido ese problema por ejemplo por llamar dos veces a Form.Init o por asignar dos veces la MainPage.

Estoy bastante convencido de que te esta dando el error al llamar a `Application.Current.MainPage = new NavigationPage(new PageNav());`y que en realidad donde esta el error es en esa pagina o en la navegacion.

Si la main page ya es una navigation page quizas deberias hacer `Application.Current.MainPage.PushAsync(new NavigationPage(new ContentPage()));`

Revisa tambien el xaml de esa pagina y el código de inicialización.